# Php DOM, getelementsbytagname, item and nodevalue returns empty list

Tags: php, html, dom, getelementsbytagname, nodevalue

I'm new here and a recent user of php. I have this problem with a DOM document that I can't get rid of.

Actually this code already work for other HTML document but it doesn't for this last one here :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://r22.csmres.co.uk/_common/js/min/yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://r22.csmres.co.uk/_common/js/min/cp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://r22.csmres.co.uk/_common/js/min/udm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://r22.csmres.co.uk/_common/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Event = YAHOO.util.Event, Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom, $ = Dom.get;
    Event.onDOMReady(function() {
        csm_search.init('search-text', 'search-btn');
        if (pagePeel != 'undefined') { sizedown987(); }
    });
</script>
<!-- S:22 -->
<!-- G:16_08_54 -->
...

<title>Awesome Title</title>
</head>
...
</html>
```

And my Php code looks like this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'NewsD');

$resultat = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

$Page = new DOMDocument();
@ $Page->loadHTML($resultat);    
$title = $Page->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I have used this code for several document (or webpage with the URL input variable) and this last one isn't working as my output $title is empty. And I can't understand why !

Thank you very much for your help !

Arthur

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump getElementsByTagName('title')?

Comment: When I do :
var_dump(getElementsByTagName('title'))  I get: object(DOMNodeList)[2]
var_dump(getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0))  I get: object(DOMElement)[4]

var_dump(getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->Nodevalue)  I get: string '' (length=0)

Makes no sense to me  !

Comment: Did this code used to work for you? I am having the exact same issue in C++. The fact that you asked this question so recently is concerning to me... I really hope an update hasn't occurred recently to break the function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem, actually a colleague of mine did !

The curlopt_returntransfer was returning a document deprived of all text. So he added this code to make sure that the function would return all of the text included in the page.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resultat = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```